# PyQt : make a Dict from Text Edit, or transform a PyQt4.QtCore.QStringList in common Dict

Tags: python, dictionary, pyqt4, qstring

I get from QtextEdit some "code", I mean something like :

```
1, A, B, D, 1
1, B, B, D, 2
2, A, C, G, 1
```

and I would like to get a dictionary like :

`table={'1':{'A':['B', 'D', '1'], 'B':[B, D, 2]}, '2':{A:['C', 'G', '1']}`

And then access it: `Var=table[1][A][B]`

but my table is : `PyQt4.QtCore.QStringList` object at `0xb50094c4`

and I get error :

```
  File "main.py", line 45, in initMachine
    self.TM.execute_TM(self.a, c, etat1) 
  File "/home/unifesp/Qt_Applications/Ruban.py", line66, in execute_TM
nvSymb=self.table[etatAct][symb][0]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The problem come from `QStringList` format ?

```
def initMachine(self):
    etat1=self.etat_1.text()
    b = self.Table.toPlainText()
    c=self.TM.obtenir_table(b)
    print c

def obtenir_table(self, code):
    code=str(code)
    self.a=code.split("\n")
    table={}
    for i in range(len(self.a)):
       b=self.a[i].split(', ')

       etat=b[0]
       symbole=b[1]
       if etat=='':
          print "ligne %i" %(i+1) + " : erreur "
       if not table.has_key(etat):
          table[etat] = {}
       if not table[etat].has_key(symbole):
          table[etat][symbole]=b[2:]
       else: 
           print "ligne %i" %(i+1) +" : already declare"
    self.table=self.convert_dict(table)

def convert_dict(self, dictionary):
    if not isinstance(dictionary, dict):
        return dictionary
    return dict((str(k), self.convert_dict(v)) 
        for k, v in dictionary.items())
def execute_TM(self, table, ruban, etat1):
    self.Ruban.position=1
    self.table=unicode(table)
    etatAct=str(etat1)
    while etatAct != 'stop':
        symb=self.Ruban.lire_cellules()
        print symb
        print table
        nvSymb=self.table[etatAct][symb][0]
        self.Ruban.ecrire(nvSymb)
        if table[etatAct][symb][1]=='D':
            self.Ruban.deplacement_droite()
        if table[etatAct][symb][1]=='G':
            self.Ruban.deplacement_gauche()
        else: 
           print "erreur code deplacement"
        etatAct=table[etatAct][symb][2]
```

I have tried many different things, here the last version of what I have tried....

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: post full traceback please....

Comment: Hi I have edited my post, is it better ? thanks.

Comment: Slightly. Can you show us the contents of `self.table` ?

Comment: when I do `print self.table`  at the end of the function `obtenir_table` I get :`{'1':{'A':['B', 'D', '1'], 'B':[B, D, 2]}, '2':{A:['C', 'G', '1']}` and when I print table in `execute_TM I get :`<PyQt4.QtCore.QStringList object at 0xb50094c4>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem came from the parameters I gave to execute the function `execute_TM`, `table`  was not a `dict`.

the input was wrong

Merci Jean-François !